# How to get variable from the json response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing problem in getting the variables from my response string. My response is like this:

```
responseText = {'page':'2','endOfPage':'yes','content':'abc'}

alert(responseText.page);
```

is returning undefined,
can anyone suggest how to do it??

Comment: I just pasted this into my browser's URL bar and it alerted `2`. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I put the code into my browser's console and it worked.
Can you show us some code around that?

Comment: @Quentin No, it isn't, but it still works in JavaScript (which is more permissive than JSON).

Comment: see this isnt working dnt know how it is working for you guys, for me it is returning undefined as value.

Comment: @Coderanonymous — You use the phrase "json response", this suggests you are getting the JSON from somewhere and that the code above is does not accurately represent the code you have. The fact that the code [works](http://jsbin.com/anezir/1/), also suggests this. Please show us what you are *really* doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your responseText is in fact a string (`responseText = "{'page':'2','endOfPage':'yes','content':'abc'}";`). You first have to parse it to create an object, this fails though because you are using single quotes, which are not valid JSON - you'll need to use double quotes for resolving the problem:

```
var json= "{ \"page\": 2, \"endOfPage\": \"yes\", \"content\": \"abc\" }";
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.page);
```

If you can't change the JSON-generator implementation to return a response with double quotes, try to replace every single quote into a double quote like this:

```
var invalidJson = "{'page':'2','endOfPage':'yes','content':'abc'}";
validJson= invalidJson.replace(/\'/g, "\"");
var obj = JSON.parse(validJson);
alert(obj.page);
```

Comment: Where does the OP display a JSON object as a string? 
This (OP): {'page':'2','endOfPage':'yes','content':'abc'}
does not equal 
This (yours): "{'page':'2','endOfPage':'yes','content':'abc'}";

You can paste the code in your JS console and it works.

Comment: Yep, the OPs code works in the console, because responseText is already an object. But because it's probably a reponse from a HTTP-request, I assumed it was in fact a string, and that's why it failed.

Comment: I think this will be more effective and correct:

validJson= invalidJson.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/\n/g, "\\\n");

Comment: Hmmm... Your replacing doesn't work (it should replace `'` by `"`, your code doesn't change the single quotes), and Firefox doesn't like `\"` in JSON. See http://jsfiddle.net/xZGML/.

Comment: Okies. Thanks anyways.

But can you suggest if i don't use JSON, and simply need to get variable values from responses string using some function can i do that? Does javascript allows that??

Answer (score -1):

- If you are using jQuery, you could use this :

> responseText = '{"page":"2","endOfPage":"yes","content":"abc"}';
>   responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
>   alert(responseText.endOfPage);

- In Javascript:

> ```
> responseText =  '{"page":"2","endOfPage":"yes","content":"abc"}';
> alert(JSON.parse(responseText).page);
> ```

which is supported in some modern browsers for parsing JSON into a native js object